# How to change value array order in javascript? ['a', 'b'] to ['b', 'a']

Tags: javascript, performance

I have this array for coordenates (latitude,longitude):

```
a = [[43.534231, -5.6646019999999995], [43.534068, -5.6646209999999995]]
```

And I'm using these libraries: openlayers & turf.

The problem is:

- openlayers is taking the coordinates as `latitude,longitude`
- turf is taking the coordinates as `longitude,latitude`

I can duplicate an array, but a few time it has a lot of elements. Could I inverse the pair:
`['a', 'b']` to `['b', 'a']`
in an easy way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the array.map function to cycle through each pair of coordinates in array `a` returning a new array with the individual values in each coord in reverse order into a new array `b`

```
var b = a.map(function(coord){
    return [coord[1], coord[0]];
});
```

You might want to add some testing to make sure each element of array `a` does itself have a pair of coordinates

Answer (score 2):

Use [reverse()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp) method.

As docs state:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.reverse(); // Mango,Apple,Orange,Banana
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bouth `map` method and `reverse` method to acheive you objective

```
array = array.map(function (coordinates) {
   return coordinates.reverse();
})
```